# how to turn off scala bracket completion in eclipse scala

Tags: eclipse, scala

In Eclipse Juno, how do I stop the automatic completion of brackets, braces and the like?

Currently when I add a { I get a } automatically. Then if I place my cursor between them and hit return to try to create a block, the cursor just moves to the right of the }. Then I have to move the cursor back between the braces, hit enter again, this time they split etc etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I think when you do that, you'll see a thin green line after the `}` before you press Enter. That's a hint where the cursor will go on Enter. Which suggests that a template is involved.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're quite right, there is a green line. I've found that if I hit 'Esc', the green line goes away and the text behaves normally :-)

Comment: Note that older versions of Eclipse (e.g. 3.7.2) don't show a green line, and seem to have different cursor behaviour in this situation.

Comment: Do you use the most actual version on Scala IDE (4.0M1)? It contains some changes in how the editor works in case of automatic brace closing.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, this setting is in `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing`

However, no equivalent setting seems to exist yet for the Scala IDE Editor.

You could request this feature (or see if it is already in progress) via the [Scala IDE GitHub page](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, actually I've found a good fix, which is just hit 'Esc' and the template functionality goes away, and the text behaves normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scala ide version 4 and above.
Go to `window -> Preferences-> Scala-> editor-> auto edits` and untick the `complete paranthesis checkbox`. All other options are also present there.